# List of files (the ones in subfolders included) older than a certain date

Tags: files, solaris, timestamps

On a Unix server (Solaris) I would like to have a list of file like the output of `ls -lrtR` (i.e. all the files of a folder, included the ones in the subfolders, with the indication of their path and date), but listing only the files older than a certain date (e.g. < 2017).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `find` utility available on your Solaris server ?

If so, then simply use `find <path> -mtime +365 -ls` or `find <path> -mtime +365 -exec ls <options of your choice> {} \;` for finding files older than 365 days.

Comment: It works but the output doesn't list the date of the file.

Comment: I edited my question to specify it

Comment: So i edited my answer ;-)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!